# Magento 2: How to add custom text after product image in product list & grid view page via custom module?

Tags: magento2, module, grid, list.phtml, list-view

How to add custom text after product image in product list & grid view page via a custom module?

I want to add custom text before the product name, like shown in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to override below xml code in your module.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\layout\catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list" template="Vendor_Extension::product/list.phtml" />
    </body>
</page>
```

2. Now copy the original file :

> vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml

to

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml

Now you can make the changes whatever you want into this overide file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have already to this way but it's not working.

Comment: Kindly check that, same file is not overide into another extension of theme. after doing the code run upgrade, deploy commands.

Comment: I have do the same as per your answer & comment but it's not working.

Comment: First confirm your module is register and enable into system.

Comment: I have done everything but it's not working. I don't know why.

Comment: Then I think you need to first confirm that, your template file is called or not on there. that is the issue only there.